# Display Woocommerce best-sellers by Current Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I would like to make a shortcode, that can be placed on category pages, for example on the sidebar.
It should display the category's best selling products.

The only solution that I find is if I specify the category, with slug or id, like below:

[best_selling_products category=”**KITCHEN-ACCESSORIES**” columns="1" per_page="5"]

How can I transform the shortcode to something like this?

[best_selling_products category=”**CURRENT-CATEGORY**” columns="1" per_page="5"]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php

```
function custom_best_selling_products( $attr = array() ){
    $string = '[best_selling_products ';
    $string .= ' category="' . get_query_var( 'term' ) . '" ';
    if( $attr ){
        foreach ( $attr as $key => $value ) {
            $string .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $value . '" ';
        }
    }
    $string .= ']';

    return do_shortcode( $string );
}

add_shortcode( 'custom_best_selling_products', 'custom_best_selling_products' );
```

This will create a custom shortcode and you can use it like this: `[custom_best_selling_products columns="1" per_page="5"]`
This shortcode will automatically get the category

Answer (score 0):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to get best selling products from current `$term` or category page -

```
function modify_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query( $query_args, $attributes, $type ) {
    if( $type != 'best_selling_products' ) return $query_args;

    $term = get_queried_object();
    if( $term ) {
        if( !isset($query_args['category'] ) ){
            $query_args['category'] = $term->slug;
        }
    }
    return $query_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'modify_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 99, 3 );
```

Add just use woocommerce default shortcode `[best_selling_products columns="1" per_page="5"]` to get the data.